# Why Mac and Linux file managers rarely have folder tree panel

Tags: linux, mac, gui

Today I had to using macOS after many months of exclusive access to Windows. I'm not a Windows fanboy, the situation just forced me to doing that.

Of course I was knowing about Finder limitations, so immediately tryied to find alternative. At the end I chose PathFinder, but of course neither of alternative managers on Mac doesn't support folder tree view.

And one observation hit me then - on Linux situation is similar. Years ago Konqeror on KDE3 had that feature, but now Dolphin, Krusader and pretty any GTK based file commander have that panel/view missing or deeply hiden.

But actually why? Over years of using Windows and Linux I always seemed that feature obvious and useful. Is it Apple quirk and Linux managers trying to be "trendy" like Apple or there are other, rational reasons?

Any idea?

Comment: Ubuntu Gnome File Explorer has a Tree left side as does Kali XFCE File Explorer. They are somewhat more rudimentary than Windows but they are also different operating systems.

Comment: Super Users's Q&A format doesn't really work for open-ended questions that are unlikely to have one true answer.

Comment: _"Over years of using Windows and Linux I always seemed that feature obvious and useful"_ - I haven't seen any statistics, but you may be in the minority.